# How to solve Bootstrap navbar hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the output below I can't see my `navbar` menu correctly. Where is the problem?

Please anyone help me.

I just changed my code `bootstrap.css` and make this line comment the line name: `padding-bottom`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="height:120px;">
  <div class="container" style="padding-top:30px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
        <a><img class="pull-left" src="images/mt-626_header_logo01.png"></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong style="color:white">SOFT</strong><strong style="color:#3EC7C2">APP</strong></a>&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- First Container -->
<div class="container-fluid fcontaner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="images/mt-0626-img.png" style="height:100%;width:100%"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 style="padding-top:150px"><strong style="color:white;">SOFT</strong><strong style="color:">APP</strong></h1>
                <h1>INNOVATIVE SOLUTIONS</h1>
                <h3 style="color:white;padding-bottom:50px;">Innovative solutions delivering a product, which <br>includes tomorrow’s technology – already today!</h3>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/mt-0626-img2.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the height from the `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="height:120px;">` if you want as suggested by Ismail.

But if you really want your `nav` to have a default height, then instead of `height` you can give `min-height` as `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="min-height:120px;">` and it will work. Your nav will expand as the content in it increases in height.

Demo:http://www.bootply.com/0JiOM9OxYW

Comment: tnx bro. i got it

Comment: If it helped you, please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height and padding-top css.

Answer (score 0):

You have added inline style here `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="height:120px;">` just remove it your problem will solve.

[**See Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/rBw3eBG5IX)

Comment: tnx but i need this height otherwise navbar will go to small.

Comment: so just add padding bottom to container

Comment: or you can use min-height instead